# Using maven-shade-plugin, how can one use dependencyReducedPom?

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm working on an open-source project ([neo4j-connector](https://github.com/alexsmirnov/neo4j-connector)) which make intensive use of [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) to include in packaged RAR the neo4j application without referencing multiple jars (seems like a limitation of maven-rar-plugin).

Anyway, when doing so, the [neo4j-connector-impl](https://github.com/alexsmirnov/neo4j-connector/blob/master/neo4j-connector-impl/pom.xml) (which uses the shade plugin) pom references neo4j as a dependency, which is not totally exact, as neo4j source code is embedded in neo4j-connector-impl jar.

I've noticed there is a [`createDependencyReducedPom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom) flag that allows one to generate a pom containing only non-shaded components. How can i use that pom instead of the standard one for dependencies of that project ?

Comment: did you ever figure something out?